# Executing parent window JS inside iframe inside Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating a chrome extension to compliment my webapp. Long story short, it creates an iframe within a content-script that hosts a site I've created previously. The iframe is loaded locally with the chrome extension.

The reason it's an iframe is because as opposed to making a pop-up with a browser-action I am trying to make it look like panel/modal within gmail. Here's an example of what it looks like

[image]

Now to the actual issue, I'm trying to execute an action within the iframe that operates on the iframe's parent window. for example `window.parent.someMethod()`. However every time I attempt that I get this error:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin 
"chrome-extension://dcihnokebmondckijoccdhbhcpkonfid" from accessing a
cross-origin frame.(anonymous function)
```

I know this has to do with the security baked into chrome-extensions and in attempt to alleviate the issue I've set my `content_security_policy` inside the manifest to `script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self';`. This did not solve my issue.

**In summary:** I'm looking for a solution inside of the chrome extension api to allow my iframe to access it's parents window.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, to the best of my knowledge.

You should instead message the content script in the tab to do something for you.

Comment: Hey thanks for the suggestion. 

I've implemented `chrome.runtime.sendMessage({greeting: "hello"});` in my iframe and  

    `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log(sender.tab ? "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url :    "from the extension");
    }
);`

in my extension. Still doesn't seem to work any ideas?

Comment: Thanks, will look into now.

Comment: should I be using `chrome.tabs.sendMessage()`

Comment: Maybe it's best to ask a separate question. I would suggest you try to fix it yourself though.

Comment: No it's true, I get caught up in "I don't want to read the docs" mentality. Which is bad. Thanks for the help, you've pointed me in the right direction.